# Using wavemaker for enterprise applications

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, wavemaker

I'm starting a new web based enterprise application, and I'm thinking of using [Wavemaker](http://www.wavemaker.com).
I'm a fairly experienced java-ee developer, but it seems to me that even in this case, WaveMaker still makes sense to develop the application fast and focus on the business logic.

My questions are :

1- Are their any drawbacks to this platform

2- Can I do all the normal things from the server side easily (like sending mail,building birt reports, adding jobs)

3- Can I freely manipulate javascript (for example for specific animations, using plugins....)

4- Can I integrate realtime processes, like websockets ?

Thank you

Comment: Only 23 questions tagged "wavemaker" - there's your drawback.

Comment: 1 - yes, there always is no matter which framework you use. 2- no, its never easy. 3 - that question doesn't make sense. 4 - what does the documentation say?

Comment: @Gimby I wanted to know real life experiences, not in theory, from someone who's using it(or used it and regretted it).

Comment: @Cuberto maybe because it's so simple, no need for questions ;)

Comment: i'm still finding some project that would be easy as wavemaker but with "better" support, but no luck... so wavemaker is one of the best choices if you use it for what is maded... make cruds :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used Wavemaker in an Enterprise application with success. We used quite advanced features such as heavy use of backend logic based on JavaServices, an run-time SQL database selector made inhouse, JS plugins for the frontend, obfuscation etc

We later recruited a devteam to take support of this application and, although the community is small, the team learn quickly and was able to maintain the code base.

**As I see it, Wavemaker is a excellent tool if you like to:**

- deploy a web-based CMS for your midsized SQL database
- deploy a smaller web control page for your java back end system

**To answer you questions:**

**1) Small community:** Although the community is friendly and on their toes, it is too small to ensure the type of feeback you might be used to. You will have to spend quite some time banging your head to the wall when you try to go beyond the example applications.

**2) Yes**, you have all the freedom you would expect from a Java backend. Simply said; each REST api is assigned to a Java Method, its up to you to implement the logic. I have built wavemaker on SQL, mongoDB. With email interactions, data parsing, file upload/download etc You name it

**3) Yes**, you can add JS plugins and customize the scripts generated by Wavemaker. You might want to make sure that you don't edit the auto generated JS, since they will be overwritten. but as soon as you found the right entry point you are free to customize just the way you like it.

**4) Yes**, since you build you own back end in java you are free to open up any type of communication you like to have. And since you are able to customize the front end js you will be able to read this data. But as I said in question 1 - there will only be a small community helping you

**So to sum it up:**
I vote for Wavemaker, but make sure to only deploy it if you application will be similar to the templates/demo provided, if you build a unique system you might like to look into other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

1. All choices have drawbacks. There is not a lot of WM expertise to be had. You'll need to deal with some issues in terms of the library at hand, dojo, spring etc instead.
2. you can,but it requires some java knowledge. You are operating in a spring MVC you can
3. you can, you are operating in a dojo client there
4. possible, probably. worth the effort, doubt it.

Comment: So mainly if I have basically a CRUD app with some events, anything i might regret by using wavemaker instead of only Spring for instance ?

Answer (score -1):

1- Drawbacks- It's enterprise focused platform, so will require own effort to learn it.

2- Yeah, you can do pretty much all normal things (at least from my experience, till now)

3- The tool has kind of open-source configuration so its easy to manipulate or customize your codes if needed

4- From my experience, [WaveMaker](http://wavemakeronline.com) has one of the best and most diverse integration options available.